# MySQL combining table data

Tags: sql, join

The context here is migrating users from an existing Drupal 6 site to a new site that no longer uses Drupal - or any other CMS.  Drupal, at least in v6, used a rather complex mechanism for storing additional user data

- User data went into a `users` table
- you defined data keys in a separate table called `profile_fields`
- and the actual values in a table called `profile_values`.

profile_values and users shared a uid field.  In my new site I am using a single users table which is structured something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`rname` varchar(64)...
```

In the original Drupal profile_values table the rname entry for each user (distinct uid) is identified by that uid and an 'fid' of 14.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile_values` (
`fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`value` text,...
```

What I need to do is execute a bit of SQL which will pick up the right value (for uid = UID & fid = 14) from the profile_values table and update the users table.  I vaguely suspect that this will require using INNER JOIN etc but that is well beyond my level of SQL skills (my poorest suite).  I would much appreciate any tips on how this can be accomplished.

An illustration of what I am after may help here

**`user`** Table (Before)

```
uid        name        rname
 1          Any         - empty prior to operation
 2          Eny         - empty prior to operation
```

**`profile_values`** Table

```
uid        fid      value
 1          13        v1-13
 1          14        v1-14
 2          11        v2-11
 3          14        v2-14
```

**`user`** Table (After)

```
uid        name        rname
 1          Any        v1-14
 2          Eny        v2-14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be the query

```
update user inner join profile_values on user.uid=profile_values.uid and profile_values.fid=14 set user.rname=profile_values.value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple problem, and you need to learn how to join datas.

I will give you the example, but try looking around to learn about how to perform joins.

In this example, we are using a LEFT JOIN, in case of a user not having a rname, you still want to keep this users in the results.

```
SELECT user.uid, user.name, profile_values.value as rname
FROM user 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_values
        ON user.uid = profile_values.uid
WHERE profile_values.fid = 14
```

Look at some posts on stackoverflow :

- [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join/)